# Background is black in image.clipTo in Fabric.js

Tags: image-processing, svg, coffeescript, fabricjs

I am in the process of making a `Fabric.js` based application that users can upload images and make posters. Recently I started work on a `clip` function to crop images using a path drawn by the user.

**How it works:** User selects an image from the canvas and clicks on a `crop` button. The `activeElement` is choose from the canvas, its `image src` is extracted. This SRC is used to place an image on a `canvas` on a `Bootstra Modal`. The user clicks on the image where a path will be drawn and finally crops the image.

Once the crop button is clicked, a SVG path is made from the dot points. Then this value is used to crop the image.

**Issue:** If the image is a PNG with no background ( we only use PNGs ), it will make the background 'black'.

[image: Image background getting black after clipping]

Below, `@_path` refers to the fabric. Path object created using a svg path by user clicks. `@_image` is image `fabric.Image`.

```
clipPath: () ->
    path_x = @_path.getLeft() -  ( @_image.getWidth() / 2 )
    path_y = @_path.getTop()- ( @_image.getHeight() / 2 )
    @_path.setLeft path_x
    @_path.setTop path_y
    # console.log 'Fill white'
    # @_image.setFill('white')

    @_image.clipTo = ( ctx ) =>
      @_path.render( ctx )

    @_image._clipToPath = @getPathSVG() 
    @_canvas.renderAll()
    return
```

I tried `@_image.setFIll('white')` and `@_image.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255,255,255,1)'` but doesn't seem to be having an effect.

**Questions**:

1. Have I clipped/cropped the image the correct way ( ie: using `clipTo` )? Why do you think
2. Why do you think the image is black where there was trnsparency?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're clipping `fabric.Image` via `fabric.Path` and the image background becomes black?

Comment: To be precise, a background that is transparent. For example if I group that with lets say a white color box ( such a way that the image is on top ) it wouldn't happen where the box is. But beyond the box the 'black' is there... What I am doing is using a `fabric.Path` object created using a `svg` path to `clip_to`.

Comment: I think a minimal jsfiddle would be very helpful here

Comment: Sure kangax, Its a big mesh of Coffee classes, let me untangle and copy some code to make a small jsfiddle. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: can you share the code you have written to clip image